# CURL inside script is not working as expected for VCD api's

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to do cURL to a vcloud director api. This works completely fine when tried from terminal, but it fails when tried inside bash script with variable substitution.

This is my script which is not working:

```
token=" valid token"
URL="vcdurl"
auth_header=\"x-vcloud-authorization:${token}\"
curl -i -k -H "Accept:application/*+xml;version=1.5" -H "${auth_header}" -X GET $URL/api/vdc/7f252c90-eb3b-43c4-a5ef-458e5bf22c0e > test.txt
echo `cat text.txt`

Error :HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
```

The following works fine:

```
curl -i -k -H "Accept:application/*+xml;version=1.5" -H "x-vcloud-authorization: valid token" -X GET https://vcdurl/api
```

Spent couple of days to figure out but I am stuck here.

Comment: get rid of the \" and use -v to let curl show you what it's doing

Comment: Syntactic and literal quotes are entirely different things. You can't use one as a substitute for the other.

Comment: Hi charles , do you mean to use curl like this ? 
curl -i -k -v -H "Accept:application/*+xml;version=1.5" -H ${auth_header} -X GET $URL/api/vdc/7f252c90-eb3b-43c4-a5ef-458e5bf22c0e > test.txt
It still shows error. Plz note , I have removed the \".

Comment: Please follow my answer *exactly* -- your comment here is missing some syntactic quotes.

Comment: BTW, to debug this yourself -- consider comparing what you get running `bash -x yourscript` with `set -x` followed by your working command.

Comment: ...so, you removed the `\"`s in `auth_header=...`, which are the literal quotes that were messing you up, but you also removed the `"`s in in the `"${auth_header}"`, which are syntactic quotes that you need.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/, which will find and report on places where you're missing syntactic quotes that are mandatory for correctness.

Comment: There seems to me no error in shellcheck .net. With -v option i do compare the requests and both seems to have same header / api info. But the response differs.
GET /api/vdc/7f252c90-eb3b-43c4-a5ef-458e5bf22c0e HTTP/1.1
11:52:54 > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
11:52:54 > Host: vcore2-us01.oc.vmware.com
11:52:54 > Accept:application/*+xml;version=1.5
11:52:54 > x-vcloud-authorization: MI7dteGY4Nxhkccrio9UJmZr6zumSjUjA5Som/JRVb0=

Answer (score 0):

```
token=" valid token"
url="https://vcdurl"
auth_header=x-vcloud-authorization:${token}

curl -i -k -X GET \
  -H "Accept:application/*+xml;version=1.5" \
  -H "${auth_header}" \
  "$url/api/vdc/7f252c90-eb3b-43c4-a5ef-458e5bf22c0e" \
  | tee test.txt
```

Note that:

- A leading `https://` has been added to the URL variable's definition, to bring it to parity with the working manually entered command.
- We're quoting the expansion of `$URL`. (Also, note the change to lower-case; see [POSIX conventions for environment variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) -- since shell variables share a namespace with environment variables, honoring these conventions avoids collisions with environment variables having meaning to the system or shell).
- We're no longer injecting *literal* quotes into `auth_header`. (Unlike *syntactic* quotes, which are parsed by the shell, *literal* quotes are treated as data, and thus passed through to `curl`).
- The (very buggy) `echo $(cat test.txt)` is gone. (A sane way to write that would just be `cat test.txt`, by the way; that said, even `echo "$(cat test.txt)"` would remove the worst of the undesired behaviors; `printf '%s\n' "$(<test.txt)"` would be even better, avoiding the need for either a subshell *or* an external utility [as `cat` is not built into the shell itself, and thus has overhead to invoke]).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers ... After addressing your comments , this is the error message i am hitting

Comment: 11:35:17 *   SSL certificate verify ok.
11:35:17 > GET /api/vdc/7f2HTTP/1.1
11:35:17 > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
11:35:17 > Host: vcore2-us01.oc.vmware.com
11:35:17 > Accept:application/*+xml;version=1.5
11:35:17 > x-vcloud-authorization: bs90IgbYa0ctWvpn/47TIarV/s4ip4Y6whWTjp5/EV4=
11:35:17 < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
11:35:17 < Connection: close
100    10    0    10    0     0    199      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   200
11:35:17 * Closing connection 0
11:35:17 (23) Failed writing body
11:35:17 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
11:35:17 Connection: close

Comment: This is my script :
url="valid url"
auth_header=x-vcloud-authorization:${token}
curl -i -k -X GET -v -H "Accept:application/*+xml;version=1.5" \
-H "${auth_header}" \
"$url/api/vdc/7f252c90-eb3b-43c4-a5ef-458e5bf22c0e" | tee test.txt

Comment: Could you put this as multi-line content in https://gist.github.com/ or a similarly ad-free pastebin? (And while you're at it, the output from both `bash -x yourscript` and `set -x; the-working-manual-curl-command-here` wouldn't hurt to have either).

Comment: I have added the script here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3b361b45c84bb55be89e5d39d14be56a

Comment: You still have a ton of literal quotes in your script. Literal quotes are almost without exception evidence of Doing It Wrong. There's not one backslash in my answer here except as a line continuation; that's for a reason.

Comment: I don't do `pastebin.com` -- that's why I asked for a gist. (It's full of ads, and its owners have indicated that they don't care who they sell ad space to).

Comment: the literal quotes are in echo statement which is used for reference. Do you see it anywhere else ? I can remove the echo statements but anyways it wont help here correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118258/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-user3780647).

Comment: Here is the gist.github url : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/64ee19f6ce346907f76643724eb1cc1f